# Drawing an image between a random height and width

Tags: android

I'm currently new to Android and I am having a bit of difficulty.
Currently the image just draws on screen at the size of the bitmap, however what I am looking to do is that everytime the application is launched (or ran in the emulator) the bitmap will draw at a random height and width between a defined maximum and minimum value.

I have no idea on how to go about this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int myRandomWidth = r.nextInt(maxWidthValue - minWidthValue) + minWidthValue;
int myRandomHeight = r.nextInt(maxHeightValue - minHeightValue) + minHeightValue;

Bitmap b = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.myBitmap);
b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, myRandomWidth, myRandomHeight, false);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```